# Focus problem on input form only on device with touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, prestashop

I have a form that shows up when I click on a search button like so :
[image: input not working]

See above that the mouse doesn't find the input and isn't clickable. If I try to click on it, it closes the window (same as if I pressed Esc button).

We found that the issue occurs on Surface Pro and on mobile phone (I guess it's because of touchable screen).

> If I take a computer without touchable screen, it's working fine - see screenshot : 
>   [image: input working image]

Here is my HTML form :

```
<form method="get" action="//revendeur-sport.kettler-france.com/recherche" class="dropdown-menu" id="search_form" style="display: block;">
    <input name="controller" value="search" type="hidden">
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span><input name="s" value="" placeholder="Chercher dans notre catalogue" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    <button type="submit">
        <i class="icon icon-search2"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

And Here is my CSS :

```
élément {

    display: block;

}
#header .search-widget.open .dropdown-menu {

    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

}
#header .search-widget .dropdown-menu {

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);

}
.popup-over .dropdown-menu {

    right: 0;
    left: auto;

}
.search-widget .dropdown-menu {

    background: none;
    border: none;
    min-width: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: none;

}
.open > .dropdown-menu {

    display: block;

}
.search-widget form {

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px 0px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px 0px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.35);
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px 0px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.35);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px 0px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px 0px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.35);

}
.search-widget form {

    position: relative;

}
.dropdown-menu, .popup-content {

    animation: animationmenus ease 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation: animationmenus ease 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation: animationmenus ease 0.5s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: none;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation: animationmenus ease 0.5s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation: animationmenus ease 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
.dropdown-menu {

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;

}
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #666666;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
0% {

    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);

}
100% {

    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);

}
0% {

    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 10px);
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);

}
```

You can find the website in question at : https://revendeur-sport.kettler-france.com/

**EDIT : It works fine on Internet Explorer & Edge. But doesn't on Firefox (last update) & Chrome (last update)**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: actually, the devices have hover feature so they know how to treat. 
in touch devices there is no hover and mouse events functions, if you want to verify, try google in your mobile browser

Comment: @MUsmanNadeem Thanks for your reply, is there any solution to avoid this behaviour ? Maybe I need to explicitly add some :hover actions ? My website has to work on every device in a correct way.